# How can I add a custom footer to Sphinx documentation?

Tags: templates, python-sphinx, footer

If I have some documentation, like for example [Galleria's documentation](https://github.com/GalleriaJS/galleria), how can I set it up so that when I run the `make html` command it will add a custom footer to each page?

I saw that I could potentially use [the LaTeX preamble](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/latex.html) section of `conf.py` if I was outputting it to a PDF format.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You have to extend the default layout by providing an html file like this:

```
{% extends '!layout.html' %}

{% block footer %}
        <!-- your html code here -->
{% endblock %}
```

Save this in a `_templates/` subdirectory as `layout.html` and make sure to tell `conf.py` where to find this directory:

```
# Add any paths that contain templates here, relative to this directory.
templates_path = ['_templates']
```

More information on templating can be found here: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/development/templating.html#templating

Comment: You can also find the layout.html file that you are overriding in your sphinx install directory. Then you can copy out the {% block %} section and override it per UncleZeiv's instructions, changing only the bits you want to change. My file was at <pythondir>\Lib\site-packages\Sphinx-1.1.3-py2.7.egg\sphinx\themes\<themename>\layout.html

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, the default location for the `_templates` directory (based on the `templates_path` setting in `conf.py`) is in the same directory that `conf.py` is in, which should be your `source` directory.

Also, if you want your footer to have the same styling as the default footer, you will need to surround your footer's HTML in a `<div class="footer">` tag.

Comment: Is there a way to change the footer in the generated PDF? I am getting "CONTENTS" there, and while this solution works for the html, it would be nice to know the PDF version, too!

Comment: > If you override a block, call {{ super() }} somewhere to render the block’s content in the extended template – unless you don’t want that content to show up: [docs](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.4.9/templating.html#jinja-sphinx-templating-primer).

Comment: For RTD theme: `{% extends '!footer.html' %} {% block extrafooter %} <!-- your html code here --> {% endblock %}`

Comment: I needed to add a link which would reference the document itself, so far the {{sourcename}} looks most reliable