# How to include publishing notes in Sphinx documentation?

Tags: python-sphinx, documentation-generation, web-publishing

I would like to include a link to our **publishing notes** in the footer of Spinx html outout, next to the Copyright notice.

- I tried to include a link in the `copyright` notice in `conf.py`. However, that is not rendered as expected. I tried several formats for the link and none worked so far.

  ```
  copyright = '2023, Foo. Also see `PUBLISHING NOTES <https://www.foo.de/en/publishing-notes.html>`_'
  ```

[image]

- There does not seem to be an extra Sphinx option for the publishing notes.

=> What is the recommended way to include publishing notes in the (html output of) Sphinx documentation?

=> Or asked in a more general way: how can I adapt the `html footer` that contains the copyright notice (and that is shown below each content page)?

**Edit**:

I also tried

```
html_theme_options = {
    'footer': '<a href="https://www.foo.de/en/publishing-notes.html">PUBLISHING NOTES</a>'
}
```

without luck.

**Related**:

https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx_rtd_theme/issues/1490

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**a)** With `sphinx_rtd_theme`

- Create a file `_templates/footer.html` inside the sphinx `source` folder with following content:

  ```
  {% extends "!footer.html" %}
  {% block extrafooter %}
      <p><a href="https://www.foo.de/en/publishing-notes.html">PUBLISHING NOTES</a></p>
      {{ super() }}
  {% endblock %}
  ```
- Reference the theme and `_templates` directory in `conf.py`:

  ```
  html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'
  templates_path = ['_templates']
  ```

[image]

Also see https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx_rtd_theme/issues/349

**b)** Without `sphinx_rtd_theme`

See following related SO question on how to override the default layout:

[How can I add a custom footer to Sphinx documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585250/how-can-i-add-a-custom-footer-to-sphinx-documentation)

**_templates/layout.html**:

```
{% extends '!layout.html' %}

{% block footer %}
        <!-- your html code here -->
{% endblock %}
```

That layout will probably not be applied if you specify an explicit theme. With an explicit theme use some theme specific options like shown in a)